# Sub Panel Remote Control?

Tags: lighting, subpanel

I would like to know if it is possible to have a relay control power to a sub panel? I am thinking of wiring a cottage with most of the lights in one sub panel. I would like to be able to power this off / on via a switch at the front door. When I leave I hit the relay and power is cut to most of the lights. Is this feasible?

Comment: It's certainly possible. It's a question of cost. How many AMPs are you thinking?

Comment: Probably need the relay to control a contactor, which will do the actual cutout. Another thought: A generator transfer switch has all the components and the design testing for peace of mind.  If you transfer to a non-existent generator, you shut the panel off...

Comment: How much current are you looking to control? Also, what make and model is your main panel? A shunt trip breaker would be the simplest way to do this and not all manufacturers make shunt trip breakers...